# proper way to capture meaningful sql exception

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, exception, jdbc

In my java try - catch clause, I want to be able to capture the exact cause of a sql exception (I am using Postgres, but this question applies for all jdbc drivers). What I had to do is

```
} catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Rollback only
        ex.printStackTrace();
        String message = ex.getMessage();
        Throwable cause = ex.getCause();
        if (cause instanceof ConstraintViolationException){
            SQLException exc = ((ConstraintViolationException)cause).getSQLException();
            if (exc instanceof BatchUpdateException){
                SQLException nextEx = ((BatchUpdateException)exc).getNextException();
                if (nextEx instanceof PSQLException){
                    message = ((PSQLException)nextEx).getMessage();
                }
            }
        }
        throw new RecordServiceException(message); 
    }
```

This is just awful, and only works for a very specific type of exception. Isn't there a more generally valid way to capture a meaningful sql exception?

Comment: Is there a reason this question is not tagged as java?

Comment: Yes, working with SQLException is indeed "just awful". [Apache ExceptionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ExceptionUtils.html) helps a bit. In general, you're supposed to rely on the SQLState as much as possible rather than working with exception class matching.

Answer (score 0):

From oracle docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlexception.html

```
public static void printSQLException(SQLException ex) {

    for (Throwable e : ex) {
        if (e instanceof SQLException) {
            if (ignoreSQLException(
                ((SQLException)e).
                getSQLState()) == false) {

                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
                System.err.println("SQLState: " +
                    ((SQLException)e).getSQLState());

                System.err.println("Error Code: " +
                    ((SQLException)e).getErrorCode());

                System.err.println("Message: " + e.getMessage());

                Throwable t = ex.getCause();
                while(t != null) {
                    System.out.println("Cause: " + t);
                    t = t.getCause();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```